# Is it possible to manually calculate standard deviation for a multiply-imputed survey variable based on the standard error (SE)?

Tags: standard-deviation, survey, multiple-imputation

I am analyzing a multiply-imputed complex sample survey data using Stata. For normally distributed numerical variables I want to report the mean and standard deviation. However, the Stata command for estimating mean of a multiply-imputed survey data `mi estimate: svy: mean [varlist]` does give the standard error of the mean, not the standard deviation. I tried to search for valuable help using Google but in vain. My question is this: Under such circumstances, is it possible to obtain an unbiased estimate of the standard deviation using the formula $\sigma$ $=$ $SE$ $\Huge.$ $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: i know.  the answer to your question depends on the microdata.  is it one of the ones covered on http://asdfree.com?

Comment: Not covered on asdfree.com. I collected my own data from a population of university students using a two-stage stratified cluster sampling technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to get to the standard deviation of the population distribution, you should `mi xeq : generate y2 = y*y` the squares of the variables, and then

```
mi estimate (sd : sqrt( _b[y2] - _b[y]*_b[y] ) ) : svy : mean y y2
mi testtransform sd
```

Note that the interface of multiple imputation and inference with complex survey data is *extremely* poorly researched into given the ubiquity of the issue. I outlined the literature and the steps [elsewhere on statalist](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2014-02/msg00846.html).

Comment: Should I do the `mi xeq: generate y2 = y*y` on M=0 and then follow it by `mi update`or just do it on one of the imputations M=1 or M=2 or ... or M=20?

Comment: `mi xeq` should do it on all of them at once.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: NO, you can't do that, because the relationship between the standard error and standard deviation is only valid for simple random samples.  For a longer answer look at [Stata's FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/weights-and-summary-statistics/). It does not include the issue with multiple imputation, but it shows how the standard deviation could be computed from survey data.